# Clean way to hide scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

Please note that I am very aware that there's other SO topics on this. The reason I am re-asking is that most of them are pretty outdated, so those answers still apply (basically just having one element have overflow: hidden, while the child has overflow:auto and a padding-right to "hide" the div (not really hiding it though and in my opinion is not a clean solution at all). Is there an more modern way to hide scroll bar, but still allow you to scroll that doesn't involve just throwing the scroll bar div out of sight, but actually just hiding the scroll bar? Again, I understand there are already SO questions on this, I just would like to actually get a solution to this rather than cover it with a band-aid (making the scroll bar out of sight).

Comment: Please create an example that we can look at. You can use something like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) which makes it easier for us to find a solution.

Comment: You can hide the scrollbar in browsers that use the webkit engine, however note this is not a cross platform implementation.  This question seems fairly similar to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487551/css-webkit-scrollbar-show-hide

Comment: I'm developing a hybrid mobile app so browsers don't really do me any good. I was hoping for some javascript or css to completely just make the scrollbar invisible. I noticed a lot of other SO questions from 2009 and 2010 so I was hoping something has changed since then but I don't think it has.

Comment: The shove-it-outside-an-overflow:hidden method is still state of the art afaik.

Answer (score 2):

In browsers that support the `-webkit-` prefix, use this CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
```

Or if you want it on a specific element, do this:

```
element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
```

This hides the scroll bar, but it doesn't stop it from scrolling. If you want to stop it scrolling at all, you  might have to use javascript or just make the page shorter.
 [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/0kv3g88n/) is a fiddle. Selecting the text will scroll it down, but there is no scrollbar.

This idea would be good for a mobile site, as touch screen phones have no need for a scroll bar.

Comment: Since iOS8, this doesn't work when used with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Uz7wc/

```
 body {
      padding:50px;   
    }

    .hidden-scrollbar {
      background-color:black;
      border:2px solid #666;
      color:white;  
      overflow:hidden;
      text-align:justify;    
    }

    .hidden-scrollbar .inner {
      height:200px;
      overflow:auto;
      margin:15px -300px 15px 15px;
      padding-right:300px; 
    }
```

Comment: While that is very clever, it still is just putting the scroll out of sight. There may not be an answer to my question, or the answer might just be 'no'. but I was just hoping there was some way to make the scroll bar invisible, but still allow it to scroll.

Comment: Yeah, I shared the cleanest way I know how, I really don't know if you can but I am gonna guess 'no'.